# How can i move map under marker like UBER in FLUTTER?

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I want to move a marker like Uber, I found an example in [Android](https://baraabytes.com/how-to-move-a-map-under-a-marker-like-uber/) but I need to do in Flutter, Can somebody help me?

Comment: get position from onCameraMove and add marker at that position with same markerId

Comment: @SahdeepSingh i tried marker in center for user to choose coordinates: user moves map, coordinates of center are read, marker moved to them. But i had huge lags on every move of map by user due to marker rebuilding. Answer below really solved my problem.

Comment: @EvgenyNozdrev Right answer below is fine but that is not a Marker but stacked icon over map. And Yes onCameraMove is so frequent and adding removing marker is costly, you can also use onCameraIdle instead which will be triggered only when user leaves the map.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) package, onCameraMove will always give you the lat, lng of the center of the map. So you can have a Stack and place a marker like an image at the center on top of the map.

```
               Stack(children: <Widget>[
                GoogleMap(
                  initialCameraPosition: _initialCamera,
                  onMapCreated: _mapCreated,
                  onCameraMove: (position) {
                    newLocation = position.target;
                  },
                  onCameraIdle: () async {
                    // you can use the captured location here. when the user stops moving the map.
                  },
                ),
               //This is your marker
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Icon(Icons.place),
                ),
              ])
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Drop marker on current location
2. Remove marker onCameraMove and place pin image on the middle of map in Stack
3. Remove pin image and drop new marker on current location by CameraPosition onCameraIdle